# Magento doesnt show new css changes

Tags: css, magento

I have made some changes in css file and re upload it on server but it didn't reflect on server it show me old CSS.

for example I have added border as per below code

```
.ma-bestseller-sldier-title { padding: 0 0 0 50px; background: #f58634 url(../images/bg_featured.png) no-repeat left;border-bottom: 1px solid;border-color: #f58634;}
```

but when i use debugging tool i found it always take

```
.ma-bestseller-sldier-title { padding: 0 0 0 50px; background: #f58634 url(../images/bg_featured.png) no-repeat left;}
```

when i try to run css URL in browser , I got OLD css that i have deleted.

Comment: Make sure you have your browser cache cleared as well as magento's flushed

Comment: I do all that things and also remove trash/temp file from host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush magento cache and storage cache.
If you are using apc or varnish cache you must be refresh. 
If not worked then you need to change your css file with new name and give new css file name in your xml file.

Comment: i have deleted styles.css and now renamed file as per your guidence and still i can access  styles.css from my browser.

Comment: Check your theme name and path where are you changes.

Comment: Almost certainly you think you've got the path right for your edited file but it's wrong.